# How do the following variables affect the period of a Bifilar pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

Hey everyone, I am a high school student from New Zealand and I have 4 questions concerning the period of a bifilar pendulum system. It is very much appreciated if you can answer with a detailed explanation.

1. Why does increasing the length of strings **L** increases the period of oscillation?
2. How does increasing the length of rod **r** increases the period of oscillation?
3. How does increasing the separation **D** between the two strings lowers the period of oscillation?
4. How does the strength of gravity **g** affects the period of oscillation?

The equation given is
$$T=\left(\frac{2\pi r\sqrt{L}}{\sqrt{3g}}\right)\frac{1}{D}$$

Comment: What do you need exactly? If the formula you attached is the solution of this strange pendulum, well, it contains already all the answers you need

Comment: Ah you need a "why".  I suggest you to make a drawing of this system with the rod a bit rotated; it should clarify all. The only extra brick is the lenght $r$ of the rod, that affect the rotational moment of inertia.